Unable to Capture Camera Poses on Inactive Tabs/Windows in Web Apps
Problem:
I’m working on a project where I use MediaRecorder and WebRTC to capture camera streams and analyze face, pose, and hand landmarks using MediaPipe's landmarker solutions (FaceLandmarker, PoseLandmarker, and HandLandmarker). The issue I’m facing is that when the browser tab or window becomes inactive, the camera’s frame rate drops significantly, or the stream is paused. This prevents me from capturing real-time movements or poses accurately.
Behavior Observed:
When I switch to an inactive tab or minimize the browser, the browser reduces the frame rate of the camera stream to a very minimal level, which affects the accuracy of detecting poses and landmarks. As a result, the movements become still, and the detection fails to work properly until the tab is active again.
Current Solution:
Here’s a simplified version of my solution that uses setTimeout and a MediaRecorder with landmark detection logic:
useEffect(() => {
    let faceLandmarker: FaceLandmarker;
    let poseLandmarker: PoseLandmarker;
    let handLandmarker: HandLandmarker;
    let interval: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;

    // Function to detect face and landmarks
    const detectFace = () => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current as HTMLCanvasElement;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        if (!ctx) return console.log('Failed to find canvas context');

        const drawingUtils = new DrawingUtils(ctx);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1280, 720);

        if (videoRef.current && videoRef.current.readyState >= 2) {
            const faceDetection = faceLandmarker.detectForVideo(videoRef.current, performance.now());

            // If face blendshapes are detected, update the corresponding states
            if (
                faceDetection.faceBlendshapes &&
                faceDetection.faceBlendshapes.length > 0 &&
                faceDetection.faceBlendshapes[0].categories
            ) {
                blendshapes.current = faceDetection.faceBlendshapes[0].categories;

                const matrix = new Matrix4().fromArray(faceDetection.facialTransformationMatrixes![0].data);
                rotation.current = new Euler().setFromRotationMatrix(matrix);

                riggedFace.current = Face.solve(faceDetection.faceLandmarks[0]);
            }

            const poseDetection = poseLandmarker.detectForVideo(videoRef.current, performance.now());
            if (poseDetection) {
                riggedPose.current = Pose.solve(poseDetection.worldLandmarks[0], poseDetection.landmarks[0]);
            }
        }
    };

    // Start the webcam stream and initialize the landmarks
    const startWebcam = async () => {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true,
        });

        videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
        videoRef.current.play();

        const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {});

        // Initialize the landmarkers for face, pose, and hands
        [faceLandmarker, poseLandmarker, handLandmarker] = await InitLandmarkers();

        // Handle the recording process
        recorder.ondataavailable = async (event: BlobEvent) => {
            if (event.data.size > 0) {
                detectFace(); // Trigger face detection whenever data is available
            }
        };

        
            recorder.start(10); // Capture data every 10ms
    };

    // Start the webcam stream on component mount
    startWebcam();

    return () => {
        clearInterval(interval); // Clean up the interval on unmount
    };
}, []);


What I Tried with WebWorkers: I have tried several solutions, such as using WebWorkers to run the detection in the background without relying on the main thread, but the camera stream FPS still drops when the tab is inactive, which makes detection unreliable.
Question:
Is there any way to bypass this behavior or force the browser to maintain a higher frame rate for the camera stream, even when the tab is inactive? I’ve already tried using setTimeout and WebWorkers, but I’m looking for a more reliable way to ensure smooth pose detection even when the tab is not active.
Any advice on how to handle this issue would be greatly appreciated!
